# Model doesn't update after record delete in Emberjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js

I am actually using Ajax instead of Ember-Data to do CRUD operations in my Ember app.

Scenario is whenever I am deleting a record, the model doesn't update. I have a list of projects and each project has a 'Delete' button in front of it.

Here's the action associated with Delete:

```
deleteItem: function(item){ //function for delete action
            var id = item.get('id');
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "http://pioneerdev.us/users/deleteProject/" + id,
                dataType : "json",
                success : function(data) {
                    console.log('success');
                }
            });
            alertify.success('Record Deleted!');
            window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},3000)
        }
```

As you can see I am using `location.reload` to manually reload the model. If anyone's interested he can look at the full source at my GitHub [repo](https://github.com/pioneersolutions/animator/blob/master/js/projects.js)

Is there any better way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your code with some comments. I hope it helps.

```
actions: {
  deleteItem: function(item){
    var id = item.get('id');
    var controller = this;
    $.ajax({
      type : "POST",
      url : "http://pioneerdev.us/users/deleteProject/" + id,
      dataType : "json",
      // use the success callback to safe notify the user when the record is deleted
      // in your current implementation the alert is displayed even if an error occurs in the server.
      success : function(data) {          
        // no need to location.reload, the removeObject will remove that item
        controller.removeObject(item);                    
        alertify.success('Record Deleted!');
      }
    });  
  }
},
filteredContent : function() {
  var searchText = this.get('searchText'), regex = new RegExp(searchText, 'i');

  return this.get('arrangedContent').filter(function(item) {
    return regex.test(item.projectname);
  });
  // instead of model use model.length so your template will update when some item is added or removed
}.property('searchText', 'model.length')
```

Comment: Ok. The success is triggered?

Comment: The success gets triggered, I get "Record Deleted" prompt but the model doesn't get updated.

Comment: I updated the answer, maybe now will work. Just change `model` to `model.length` in your computed property `filteredContent`

Comment: Actually I discovered something else as well, it doesn't `console.log('success')` as well.

Comment: The item is just removed when the success handler is triggered. You can make a test and put the code of success handler, outside of ajax call. So it will always be executed. And we can see if the client side is ok, and if the problem is in the server. I will sleep, and try more tomorrow.

Comment: Actually putting `controller.removeObject(item);` outside the ajax call is doing the trick for me. Anyways thanks man! *beer* for you.